# How can I push data to an array inside an async request to the database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to make a request to the database (mongoDB) and save its return in a list of objects but the list is not getting filled. Here is the code

```
router.get('/all/:studentEmail', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const student = await Student.findOne({ email: req.params.studentEmail });
        if (!student) {
            return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Student not found' });
        }
        var list = [];

        student.exercises.map(async (exercise) => {
            list.unshift(await Exercise.findById(exercise));
        });

        res.json(list);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }
});
```

The database query `await Exercise.findById(exercise)` returns correctly the object, but `res.json(list);` returns empty. Do anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue but you aren't passing an object to `res.json` -- list is an array, not an object. Maybe try `res.json({ list })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base issue is that `res.json()` executes way before `student.exercises.map(async (exercise) => {` completes. Putting `await` into `map` doesn't wait for each and every item in the async loop to process. Either use something like `Promise.all()` or use a `for` loop (other strategies can be used also). Decide which to use based on whether you can process in parallel or need to process in series. Try the following using `Promise.all` to execute async requests parallel using `then` on each `Promise` to execute an operation against `list`:

```
router.get("/all/:studentEmail", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const student = await Student.findOne({ email: req.params.studentEmail });
    if (!student) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: "Student not found" });
    }
    var list = [];

    await Promise.all(
      student.exercises.map((exercise) =>
        Exercise.findById(exercise).then((result) => list.unshift(result))
      )
    );

    res.json(list);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server error");
  }
});
```

Also, an alternative to `unshift` and just return the results if they are not nested, if they are nested you can consider `flat()`:

```
const list = await Promise.all(
  student.exercises.map((exercise) => Exercise.findById(exercise))
);

return res.json(list);
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: @BrennoLima Glad to hear it worked. Mark the answer if it helped resolve your issue. Thanks!